# Customize port for HTTPS in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I created a new ASP.NET Core web application and enabled SSL for the IIS Express debugging profile. When I clicked "Enable SSL", something decided that port 44318 would be an easy to remember number for debugging a web API.

How can I change the port to something actually easy to remember like 5000? Is there a way to have that configuration under source control so that everyone uses the same port?

[image: debug profile]

I already tried changing the App URL to `https:/localhost:5000/` but then my web app refuses to start with an error.

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application. An error occurred while sending the request.

Comment: What happens if you set the port to something in the range 44300 - 44399

Comment: @Bassie that works so I guess it's not possible to use a port outside that range.

Comment: I found instructions here for configuring a different port (requires admin privileges): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges#using-ssl